# my sql in() using sytax and fix a sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im need a small fix a query please help me, in not fixed. see on bottom, my example codes, thx for all helpers..

```
ny_xd_satilanlar database rows
id---uyid---toplam---sipno
01---16---1---1237777777
02---30---3---1301275922
03---30---2---1301741801
04---11---4---1123467988


//NOT WORK RETURN : 0 (zero)
$total_urun = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(adet) as toplam FROM ny_xd_satilanlar WHERE sipno IN ('{$curTel['sipnolar']}') AND uid='{$urunid}'"));
$total_urun = $total_urun[toplam];

// EXAMPLE 1 = NOT WORK RETURN : 0 (zero)  HOW TO FİX QUERY ????
SELECT SUM(adet) as toplam FROM ny_xd_satilanlar WHERE sipno IN ('1237777777,1301275922,1301741801') AND uid='30'

// EXAMPLE 2 = NOT WORKİNG TRUE RETURN : 3 (three)  HOW TO FİX QUERY ????
SELECT SUM(adet) as toplam FROM ny_xd_satilanlar WHERE sipno IN ('1301275922,1301741801') AND uid='30'

// EXAMPLE 1 ALTERNATİVE QUERY = OK WORK RETURN 3+2= :5 (five) 
SELECT SUM(adet) as toplam FROM ny_xd_satilanlar WHERE (sipno='1237777777' OR sipno='1301275922' OR sipno='1301741801') AND uid='30'
```

NEED A FİX SECOND QUERY ??

Comment: Drop the quotes inside the the `IN ( ... )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the `IN` values. Currently, all values are enclosed in `'`, so they behave as a single value. Anything that is wrapped in quotations will be treated as one value unless properly escaped.

```
SELECT SUM(adet) as toplam FROM ny_xd_satilanlar WHERE sipno IN (1237777777, 1301275922, 1301741801) AND uid='30'

SELECT SUM(adet) as toplam FROM ny_xd_satilanlar WHERE sipno IN (1301275922, 1301741801) AND uid='30'
```

Or, if they're supposed to be string numbers:

```
SELECT SUM(adet) as toplam FROM ny_xd_satilanlar WHERE sipno IN ('1237777777', '1301275922', '1301741801') AND uid='30'

SELECT SUM(adet) as toplam FROM ny_xd_satilanlar WHERE sipno IN ('1301275922', '1301741801') AND uid='30'
```

Comment: The data stored in the database in this way:
1314949807
1302114743,1339420308,1350483598,1351603860
1305813663,1334669076

How do you specify the data format change her shape, please write a short code for it:
'1237777777', '1301275922', '1301741801'

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the values you want the `IN` clause to work on using single quote characters:

```
SELECT SUM(adet) as toplam FROM ny_xd_satilanlar WHERE sipno IN ('1237777777','1301275922','1301741801') AND uid='30';

SELECT SUM(adet) as toplam FROM ny_xd_satilanlar WHERE sipno IN ('1301275922','1301741801') AND uid='30';
```

Comment: The data stored in the database in this way:
1314949807
1302114743,1339420308,1350483598,1351603860
1305813663,1334669076

How do you specify the data format change her shape, please write a short code for it:
'1237777777', '1301275922', '1301741801'